# How to make a Kivy app maintain consistent size, when dragging between two screens of different pixel density?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am experimenting with the sample code in the `kivy_examples` package.  On a Macbook Pro with a Retina display, that is also connected to an external monitor with standard pixel density.

When I launch any of the example apps, the window first appears on the built-in Retina display and looks fine.  When I then drag that window over to the external monitor, suddenly all of the widgets blow up in size.

There are a number of existing StackOverflow questions which deal with Kivy and pixel density.  But the questions and answers all seem to deal with single-screen use cases.  You don't know what the density of your target screen might be, so here's how to use the `dp(...)` function to configure for that screen at application startup, etc.

However, I can't find any discussion that deals with a multiple-monitor use case.  Is there any way to have a Kivy app respond dynamically to pixel density changes, as the app is moved around between multiple monitors?  As opposed to just configuring for a fixed density level at startup time?

Answer (score 0):

The [Kivy metrics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.metrics.html) contains other types of metrics than `dp` that you can use to set the size of your widgets.

In your case, if you want to maintain a constant size over your different screens, I suggest you to use the `cm` metrics to have the same real size whatever the resolution of your screen may be.